# Stack Level Too Deep Error on Calling Yield in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
names = %w(Darko Marko Sarko Harko Yarko)

  def names
    yield names.shift
    yield names.shift
    yield names.shift
    yield names.shift
    yield names.shift
  end

names do |name|
  puts name
end
```

This produces stack level too deep error. What's going on?

Comment: side note (not related to your core question): in case you did not realize `shift` modifies the array it acts upon. So the original array elements would be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's name clash.

```
yield names.shift
```

`names` here is the `def names`, not the `names = %w`

So, naturally, method goes into recursion, out of which it can't break out.

#### Update:

The reason why you get "undefined local variable" error when you rename the array (or the method) is something called "scope gate".

Basically, when a method definition is opened, current scope changes and all local variables become inaccessible. So, either pass the array as method parameter (as suggested in Steve's answer, recommended) or make the array an instance variable.

```
@name_arr = %w(Darko Marko Sarko Harko Yarko)

def names
  yield @name_arr.shift
end
```

Comment: If I try changing 'names' array to something else and change the references in the def names method, now I get undefined local variable or a method error. Hm..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that cleared a lot of things up, wish I could choose both yours and Steve answer as best, because they both provided a lot of insights on how yield&blocks work.

Answer (score 4):

It's as Sergio explained, and you need to pass the array into the method

```
array_of_names = %w(Darko Marko Sarko Harko Yarko)

def names(array_of_names)
  yield array_of_names.shift
  yield array_of_names.shift
  yield array_of_names.shift
  yield array_of_names.shift
  yield array_of_names.shift
end

names(array_of_names) {|name| puts name }
```

Comment: perfect. i dont know what @daremarkovic is trying to do , but this is how that is to be done.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is something like

```
names = %w(Darko Marko Sarko Harko Yarko)
names.each do |name|
  puts name
end
```

Not only will this let you work with variable length arrays it avoids your recursion error.

Comment: asker is confused about ruby blocks. He is not asking how to iterate a ruby array. I understand that the question is stupid , but your answer does not add any knowledge.

Comment: How do you know this is what OP wants to do and is not a good SSCCE?